# Find k in $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{k}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to solve for k in the pdf:

\begin{equation}
\int_2^{\infty} \frac{k}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2} \, dx
\end{equation}

My solution (which is wrong):

Take the square of the integral to convert to polar coordinates:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left[ \int_2^{\infty}  \frac{k}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} x^2\} \, dx  \right]^2 
&=\frac{k^2}{2\pi}  \int_2^{\infty}  \int_2^{\infty}  \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} x^2 - \frac{1}{2} y^2\} \, dx dy\\
&= \frac{k^2}{2\pi}  \int_2^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi} \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} r^2\} r d\theta  dr \quad (r^2=x^2+y^2)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The inner integral has range $0$ to $\pi$ because x has to be greater than $2$ and therefore can only be in the first or fourth quadrant.

Solving the inner integral, involving $d\theta$ would give $\pi$, so we can simplify the above to:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \frac{k^2}{2\pi} \pi \int_2^{\infty}  \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} r^2\} \, rdr =&  \frac{k^2}{2}  \int_2^{\infty}  \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} r^2\} \, rdr \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Define $u=-\frac{1}{2} r^2$. Then $\frac{du}{dr}= -r$, so $-du=rdr$. We can use this u-substitution to solve the above integral:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{k^2}{2}  \int_2^{\infty}  \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} r^2\} \, rdr =& 
\frac{k^2}{2}  \int_2^{\infty} - \exp\{u\} \, du \\
=& -\frac{k^2}{2}  \left[ \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} r^2\} \right]_2^{\infty} \\
=& -\frac{k^2}{2} [-\exp\{ -2\}]\\
=& \frac{k^2}{2} 0.13534
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Equating the square root of this to 1:

\begin{equation}
\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{0.13534} =1
\end{equation}

we get $k=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{0.13534}}=3.8442$.

But this is wrong!

`fun3<-function(x){
  return((3.8442/(sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-.5*x^2))
}> integrate(fun3,lower=2,upper=Inf)
0.087456 with absolute error < 5.8e-05`

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think you can use $Z$-table to find $k$.

Comment: The bounds when changing the variables is not correct. Draw both and you'll see  it. Also what do you mean by trying to solve $k$? Do you want to find $k$ such that the integral equals $1$?

Comment: You know (or can prove using the polar trick) that the integral from $0$ to infinity is $k/2$. And you can compute the integral from $0$ to $2$ to any desired level of accuracy.

Comment: Read about the error function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment. $k$ can be evaluated using $Z$-table.
$$
\Pr[Z>2]=\Pr[Z\le2]=\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\large\frac12x^2}\ dx.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{2}\int^\infty_{2}\exp\left(\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\right)d\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)={\mathrm{erfc}(\sqrt 2)}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$
Therefore,
$$\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^\infty_2\exp\left(\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)dx=\dfrac{k\times\mathrm{erfc}(\sqrt 2)}{2}$$

Comment: It should be
$$
\frac{k\cdot\text{erfc}(\sqrt{2})}{2}.
$$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thanks! I edited my answer.

Comment: You forget the denominator.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Again, thanks! My $14$-year old mind must be sleepy! :-P

Comment: We all did such a mistake. :)